# How much memory does Bluetooth Low Energy device has

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, altbeacon

Let's say I want to start transmitting advertising packets from a Blueooth 4 module attached to a Raspberry Pi. I am planning to use BlueZ library for the same. Have a basic questions regarding the same -

How much memory does a typical Bluetooth device contains (is it standard or something that can change from vendor to vendor) ? In both the cases, does the advertisement has to be 27 bytes (iBeacon) and 28 bytes (Altbeacon and URIBeacon) or can it be extended to any number limited by bluetooth memory size or any other guidelines? Wish to understand a little bit about this topic.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As the answer says, the size limitations are not because of Device Memory, but because of the way it is implemented. Speaking of the Device Memory as your question appears: there are a few manufacturers like Laird, BlueGiga, Murata, connectBlue, etc. Majority of them had the internal memory of 256K.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Device memory is not what limits the Bluetooth LE advertisement size.  The limitation is imposed by **the [Bluetooth 4.0 Core specification](https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=229737), which allows for a maximum of 28 bytes in a manufacturer advertisement PDU** (including the one-byte PDU length field).

While you can't transmit more data in a single advertisement, it is possible to send more data using other techniques including:

1. Interleaving multiple advertisements from the same transmitter.  You can differentiate these advertisements with a "type" byte, and then use this to stitch them together with the receiving device.  Disadvantage:  complex implementation.
2. Using a scan response packet to send additional data.  Disadvantage: scan responses may not arrive in a timely manner.
3. Provide a connectable GATT service that can be used to fetch additional data.  Disadvantage: once connected, advertising stops.
4. Use a web service to look up additional data based on a unique identifier in the advertisement.  Disadvantage:  It won't work with out an internet connection.

Comment: Two things: If the device tries to transfer more than 28 bytes, does the advertisement gets stripped or is it not allowed at all? Also, in your first approach, is it possible to set different advertising intervals for multiple advertisements or is that set at device level? How much does that effect the battery life?

Comment: The behavior when attempting to send an advertisement that is longer  than allowed by the spec varies by chipset implementation.  As you suggest, either it will either get truncated, or no transmission will happen at all.  Because the spec does not explicitly support multiple simultaneous manufacturer advertisements, you essentially have to write firmware to change the advertisement quite often.  You can make each distinct advert go at a different rate, but that increases complexity.  Power usage is largely dictated by the total number of adverts/sec that are being transmitted.

Comment: Great. That helps a lot! I guess I will continue my experimentations and hope to learn through that.